How to level "bowed" concrete floor
I am going to put a rigid insulation board on my concrete floor in the basement. However, I have a small section of the floor that is higher, which is not problematic in itself. The real issue is that the slope is bowed, not flat, which creates some space under the board. I thought about self-leveler, but I'm afraid it will just move down and won't fill the slope. How can I flatten it without increasing the height of the rest of the floor? Wanted to include a picture but it doesn't really show the problem. Thank you for any input!

Get an angle grinder and a diamond cup wheel. They work remarkably well at grinding concrete and is the perfect tool for flattening small areas. Beware that the process creates an enormous amount of dust, so be sure to wear a good quality mask, like a 3M P-100 and eye protection.

Yep, grind high spots, fill low spots.  And also hearing protection.
